# In need of good linear algebra practice exams (similar to MIT)

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question

So MIT offers a lot of good exams at this web-site: [MIT Archive](http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/old.shtml)

But I'd like to ask you for some other similar resources, that have similar types of problems, like True or False etc. I know this might not hit the usual criteria for questions here, but I have found it hard to find other free and quality resources myself.

Answer (score 1):

There do exist a good amount of such resoureces: see the [Boston College archive](https://www2.bc.edu/ilker-yuce/Spring11/MT2100102/mt210test.html); the one from [Stanford](http://math.stanford.edu/~paquin/um51aS11final.html); also the one from [Portman State University](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://web.pdx.edu/~erdman/LINALG/Linalg_pdf.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwirz8-XrezRAhUJo48KHXJ-B5MQFggZMAA&usg=AFQjCNEMutEdPYBZNeleg7YaTvicKF-4fA&sig2=kh27XsBbRH3MY89XKT5Ctg). They have a good collection of interesting problems.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The UC Berkeley Math Dept. Archives also contain plenty of sample exams in Linear Algebra:

https://math.berkeley.edu/courses/archives/exams/math-110